# Black Screen in present Modal

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a code like this in my fist viewController :

```
- (IBAction)showSetting:(id)sender{
   settingView = [[settingController alloc]initWithNibName:@"settingController" bundle:nil];
   settingView.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
   [self presentModalViewController:settingView animated:YES];
}
```

and then in the second view (settingController.m) :

```
- (IBAction)closeSetting:(id)sender{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I want to set the transparency of background while showing the present modal, but it shows a blank black screen.
is there anyone can help me..

Comment: you want to show settingController transparent so that you can view your first view??

Comment: yeah.. could you help me please?

Comment: thats not possible with presentModalViewController. You need to take an overlay for this.

Answer (score 0):

Like You have a rootViewController which will present your settingView .

```
settingView .view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[rootViewController presentModalyourViewController:settingView  animated:YES];`
```

UIModalPresentationCurrentContext with Transition

```
settingView .modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
settingView .modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
```

try this

```
- (IBAction)showSetting:(id)sender{
   settingView = [[settingController alloc]initWithNibName:@"settingController" bundle:nil];
   settingView .view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    settingView .modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    settingView .modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalyourViewController:settingView  animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have already do like you said,  but the animation is not working while show the present modal.
Any idea?

Comment: No.. its become black screen again just like before.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
 settingView *settingViewObj=[[settingView alloc]initWithNibName:@"settingView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:settingViewObj];
   [nController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
   [self.navigationController  presentViewController:nController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But this is the code for iOS 6.For iOS 5 you can use

```
[self.navigationController  presentModelViewController:nController animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You can use your view controller

Comment: I fyou want you can coonect to me on skype @ashumishra224 to describe your problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30101/discussion-between-template09-and-ashutosh-mishra)

Answer (score 0):

As others explained above, you can do it with a Modal presentation using:

`settingView .modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;`

However, **if you see a different color coming from behind** is because your window has that color. Try setting the background color of your window (normally on your AppDelegate):

`window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`